# Selenium C# Click() cant get to another URL while using Jenkins

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins

I have 30 tests working locally with Selenium C# in headless mode.

The problem occurs, when I try to use Jenkins. The message is "Unable to locate element". 
It took lots of time to understand that the problem is not time wait and not frame size.

Chrome options (they say frame size will help, but its not):

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.AddArgument("--window-size=2560,1440")
co.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
co.AddArgument("headless")
```

Tested web application was made with vue.js (everything is dynamically generated).
To get the page or subpage displayed by URL Jenkins needs about 2-4 seconds:

```
driver.Url = "http://app.com/home"          //not my URL
```

And every Click() works good on a certain URL: you can click anywhere, even on a pop-up form, if the URL is the same (Click() takes about 600 ms).

But if you Click() on element which directs to another URL, the page is not displayed (even if you wait 80 seconds).

This problem could be solved by using

```
driver.Url = "http://app.com/home/menu"
```

but thats not real testing.

Comment: Does the 'click' method work locally?

Comment: Yes, locally everything works perfectly.